# How to apply na.approx to a row in a matrix?

Tags: r, interpolation, na.approx

I am trying to make an interpolation for all the rows in a dataframe. I am using `apply(data_final,2,na.approx)`. This make the interpolation for the values but some are out of range.

If I use `na.approx(data_final[8,])` instead, I get a different value at that row compared to the row using `apply`.

Also, if I do `na.approx(data_final)` I get the same result as `apply(data_final,2,na.approx)`. It doesn't make any sense since supposedly apply is applying `na.approx` function to every row in the data frame.

> apply(data_final,2,na.approx)
>   [8,]  0.63  0.49  2.40  2.65  3.65  5.80  0.96  1.85  1.43  1.25  1.21  1.20     0.91    1.00    0.96    0.80  1.42  1.82  1.910
>
> na.approx(data_final[8,])
>    [1] 0.630 0.490 0.584 0.678 0.772 0.866 0.960 1.850 1.430 1.250 1.210 1.200 0.910 1.000 0.960 0.800 1.420 1.820 1.910 1.780 1.620
>   [22] 1.650 1.380 1.370

Answer (score 0):

Because `na.approx` does columnwise calculation instead of rowwise.  According to `?na.approx` (from `zoo`), the usage is

> na.approx(object, ...)

and the parameter description is

> If obj has more than one column, the above strategy is applied to each column.

---

Using a reproducible example

```
library(zoo)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(2, NA, 3, 4), col2 = c(1, 3, NA, 2))
na.approx(df1)
#     col1 col2
#[1,]  2.0  1.0
#[2,]  2.5  3.0
#[3,]  3.0  2.5
#[4,]  4.0  2.0
```

columnwise applying `na.approx`

```
sapply(df1, na.approx)
#     col1 col2
#[1,]  2.0  1.0
#[2,]  2.5  3.0
#[3,]  3.0  2.5
#[4,]  4.0  2.0
```

Comment: So, if I want the second output I have to iterate through the data frame get each row as a vector and use na.approx?

Comment: @CarlomagnoAmaya  What is your requirement?  Is it to get NA filled by row or column?

Comment: Is to interpolate the whole row, as a vector. Not as a 2 dimensional object.

Comment: @CarlomagnoAmaya  In that case use `df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, na.approx))`